# How do you create a nested list using the Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can someone explain how I would create a nested list using the Ionic Framework? I am using ng-repeat for my first list and each item has a collection that I want to place in a nested list. I used ng-repeat again on the inner list as well and also used "list card" css classes for the inner list. Its not working as expected.

Can someone quickly explain how they would do this (preferably with sample code)? The few attempts I have made do not work as expected. I have tried using the "list card" class and then using that again in that class again in the inner list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you liked it, so it doesn't show up in the unanswered :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it like this?

```
$scope.lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];

<div class="list">
   <div class="list list-inset" ng-repeat='list in lists'>
      <div class="item" ng-repeat='item in list'>
        {{item}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ion-tree-list](https://github.com/fer/ion-tree-list)? However, the problem is that the performance needs to be improved over a large no. of nodes (1000+)?